# Amazon EC2 instance lost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-elb

I have an Amazon EC2 instance with AutoScaling and Load balancer.

I deployed an application and configured Apache.

Everything went fine but Amazon for some reason terminated my instance and started a new one. I lost all the code and configuration there?

What should I do? 
Maybe attach a EBS volume and deploy everything there? But my Apache server is installed on the main volume.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using autoscaling, instances will be terminated if they become unhealthy. In order to use autoscaling effectively, you should not keep any persistant data on the instance itself. This is called Shared Nothing architecture.

What you want to do, is create an AMI that has all your application and or tools to bootstrap your application. You would use this AMI as part of the launch configuration for your autoscale group. So if a new instance gets launched, either due to failure or needing to scale, your application will be back up without any interaction from you.

Comment: And my PHP will be on the EBS volume right? What do you think?

Comment: Yes it will be on an EBS volume. Generally when you launch a new instance, it automatically creates a root EBS volume (Unless you are using instance store AMI's).

Comment: I had a root EBS volume but it went away.

Comment: This is my beanstalk log:
Added EC2 instance 'i-1b04902f' to Auto Scaling Group 'awseb-e-4bcikc8nak-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1NKMVJFSBHIVE'.
Adding instance 'i-1b04902f' to your environment.
Removed instance 'i-1b04902f' from your environment. (Reason: Instance is in 'shutting-down' state)
Removed instance 'i-4f99f67b' from your environment. (Reason: Instance is in 'shutting-down' state)

Comment: What happened? Can you explain?

Comment: Root EBS volumes do get deleted by default with instance termination. If you properly set up autoscaling, this should not matter.

Comment: I set up autoscaling using Beanstalk so it was pretty automatic. But I have to configure apache, and some versions, It will get lost if it is deleted. What do you mean with properly setup autoscaling?

Comment: What is the properly configuration?

Comment: Yeah. If you are starting with an AMI that has everything configured, then you should be fine.

Comment: I started from scratch creating it using beanstalk. If I understand what you are saying, after configuring everything we should create an AMI,, and then?